# My query is duplicating results? MySQL / PHP/ Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

To make this a simple as possible to understand I am going to give you all the details I can so I can figure out this problem.

---

Okay so my problem is that my query that fetches me **ONE** record from my database is returning what appears to be duplicate values of the same record in multiple arrays. When I check my query result all my tables are duplicated and placed into arrays - one array for each duplicated record (or row).

The cause of this I think is my 1 --> Many relationship table (Procedure --> Procedure_event)

Here is my shema (you will see procedure and procedure_event) are 1: M relationship.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SggnD.png

---

[Here](http://pastebin.com/pc53Pmgf) is my query result as you can see my tables **(apart from procedure event)** are repeated with the same data in each array. The quantity of arrays  returned is dependant on how many **procedure_event** rows there are linked to **procedure**.

In this list there are three! --> http://pastebin.com/pc53Pmgf

To illustrate to you what is happening here is a diagram:

Query Result:

> procedure row x ---> procedure_event row x
>
> procedure row x ---> procedure_event row x+1
>
> procedure row x ---> procedure_event row x+1

What I want to returned is this (no duplication of other tables):

> procedure row x ---> procedure_event x
>
> ```
>            ---> procedure_event x+1
>
>             ---> procedure_event x+1
> ```

---

**Here is my query in Codeigniter Active Record**

```
public function view_record($record_id)
        {
            //The criteria used for WHERE is a variable with array of procedure_id = record_id that is passed to function
            //e.g. Record id = 2419
            $criteria = array 
            (
                'procedure_id' => $record_id
            );

            //this selects the columns from procedure table for use in joins 
            $this->db->select('*');
            //this is the table I want to use the columns from
            $this->db->from ('procedure');

            //this joins the patient row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
            $this->db->join('patient', 'patient.patient_id = procedure.patient_id', 'left');

            //this joins the department row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
            $this->db->join('department', 'department.department_id = procedure.department_id', 'left');

            //this joins the procedure_name row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table
            $this->db->join('procedure_name', 'procedure_name.procedure_name_id = procedure.name_id', 'left');

            //this joins the dosage row that matches its ID to the patient ID in the procedure table]
            $this->db->join('dosage', 'dosage.dosage_id = procedure.dosage_id', 'left');

            //----->This is what is causing the problem -- try a different JOIN?
            $this->db->join('procedure_event', 'procedure.procedure_id = procedure_event.procedure_id' , 'left');

            //this selects the row in procedure table that matches the record number
            $this->db->where('procedure.procedure_id', $record_id);

            //gets all the data from the query
            $result = $this->db->get();


            //
            if ($result->num_rows >0)
            {
                return $result->result();
            }

            else
            {
                return FALSE;

            }


        }
```

I hope this is clear to everyone. I hope there is a way to solve this otherwise I am going to be stuck as I do not know how to deal with all this repeated data as it is messing up my foreach loops.

In the words of Princess Leiah

> "Help me Obi'wan, your my only hope!"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want the procedure_event to be returned as a nested array?  Is this right?

If so, I'm not sure if Codeigniter offers a way to do that directly.  Your best bet is probably to process the arrays that you are currently getting using php, to put the data into the nested non-duplicate format that you want.

You could also break it down into 2 queries.  One to get all the procedure data, using all the joins but leaving out the procedure_event joint.  Then do a second query where you just join procedure to procedure_event.  It would then be a simply matter to loop through the result and prepare the data the way you would like it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to process the query result array in php like following.

```
$result = $this->db->get();
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
  $result_arr[$value->procedure_id] = $value;
}
```

and then

```
return $result_arr;
```